# How to add a favorite item to a newly created list

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Would like to know, how to get a favorited item (in this case Elements A till C) to appear in only one specific, newly created list (which can be created by a user).

For now, when I favorite an element, I get to see it in every of my newly created lists. Below is an example (sorry for the missing styling, used only `<br />`):

[image: Web-app with 2 newly created lists and added Elements]

I assume, that it can be done with lists id (similar to how I delete the lists or favorites), but need a better understanding of it.
Also I got a warning inside Chrome, that the child elements have no key value. I tried to add `shortId` inside .map in `<li>` (like `<li key={shortid.generate()}>`, but am afraid, that my solution is not an optimal one and it should be placed somewhere else (just where?)).

Here is my CodeSandbox [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/playing-with-creating-lists-m94h9?file=/src/components/App.jsx)

Any help is welcome.

Comment: just so that I get this right, you don't want the favorite to be on all items ? to be honest I don't understand the whole logic here. Wouldn’t it be better if you create an item and then you pick a "task" that you want to favorite ?

Comment: Yes, you understand me well. The logic comes from a beginner. How would you do this?

Comment: I would make it like this. I would have a separate list for favorites. and each of the items should have these properties "created", "id","name", "isFavorite". So think of it like this.
You add three items to the list named "A", "B" and "C". then each of those items has a favorite button next to them and when you click on the favorite it should  still be in the list, but it should also appear at the top in the "favorite" list. So you are doing a filter to only show if an item has the key isFavorite to true or else it won't display them

Comment: So actaully it is similar to my approach. I am creating a separate favorites list and then showing it in the created lists. But as I understand, I should hide the items, that appear in all of the lists?

Comment: you favorite list should filter and only show favorit

Comment: Yes, just how to choose the right list, thats the whole point about my question :/.

Comment: I will write an answer with a codeSandbox example

Comment: Thanks, still waiting :-).

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. hade some stuffs to do.

Comment: If that did solve your problem, don't forget to approve that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked something together here.
There are some improvements that can be made like adding typescript and less code, but I did make it so that you could follow along since I don't know the level of your coding skills.

and here is a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-breeze-0cw92?file=/src/App.js:0-1562) link

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const addItem = () => {
    const newItem = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      fav: false,
      title: inputValue
    };
    setItems((oldState) => [...oldState, newItem]);
    setInputValue("");
  };

  const makeFav = (id) => {
    console.log("id prop", id);

    const allItems = [...items];
    const itemIndex = allItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    allItems[itemIndex].fav = !allItems[itemIndex].fav;
    setItems(allItems);
    console.log("itemIndex", itemIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add item"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => addItem()}>Add</button>
      <hr />
      <h2>Favorites</h2>
      {items
        .filter((item) => item.fav === true)
        .map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              {item.title}
              <button onClick={() => makeFav(item.id)}>un fav</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      <hr />
      <h2>list</h2>
      {items
        .filter((item) => item.fav === false)
        .map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              {item.title}
              <button onClick={() => makeFav(item.id)}>fav</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, its not an answer I am seeking for. My desired output would be, when one has 2 favorite lists and could choose, to which one of them one could add a favorited item.

Comment: Okej, that is not what your question is about :D. Okej, since you want to be able to choose on to what list you want to add it to you could just change the "add fav" button into a dropdown list save the value of that drop down and then just list all your "favorite lists" then you just need to loop over your "favorite list" and see if that matches the favorite list on the object inside of your array list

Comment: Well, sorry for my bad explanation :P. A dropdown list like react-select? Thanks for all the advice, will try to implement it.